# Are objects with the same id always equal when comparing them with ==?

Tags: python, equality

If I have two objects o1 and o2, and we know that

```
id(o1) == id(o2)
```

returns **true**.

Then, does it follow that

```
o1 == o2
```

Or is this not always the case? The paper I'm working on says this is not the case, but in my opinion it should be true!

Comment: "this is not the case, but in my opinion it should be true!" -- note that "not the case" and "should be true" aren't mutually exclusive ;-) People *should* implement the `==` operator as a reflexive relation, but in some cases they choose not to (`WeirdEquals` below) and in some cases they even find a reason not to, perhaps due to external constraints (IEEE NaN).

Comment: In fact, to expand on the above, people should almost certainly implement `__eq__` as an equivalence relation (reflexive `assert a == a`, symmetric `if a == b: assert b == a`, transitive `if a == b and b == c: assert a == c`).

Comment: Other than NaN and concurrency, what are some other common instances where `==` is not reflexive for a specific purpose?

Comment: @MartyMacGyver but vanilla Python has neither of those

Comment: @cat The nan instance works as below (after importing math) and I would expect the threading one does as well so I'm not sure what you mean by "vanilla" - I'm considering the default packages that install with Python as a baseline. I'm asking about those as well as any other common packages that are well-known for this idiosyncrasy.

Answer (score 129, accepted):

Not always:

```
>>> nan = float('nan')
>>> nan is nan
True
```

or formulated the same way as in the question:

```
>>> id(nan) == id(nan)
True
```

but

```
>>> nan == nan
False
```

[NaN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaN) is a strange thing. Per definition it is not equal nor less or greater than itself. But it is the same object. More details why all comparisons have to return `False` in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1565164/what-is-the-rationale-for-all-comparisons-returning-false-for-ieee754-nan-values).

Comment: @AdamSmith, why this is a more real case than the accepted answer?

Comment: @J.C.Leitão -- this is because the accepted answer simply redefines `__eq__` to behave nonsensically for a certain trollish class of objects, but the behavior described here is present in a built-in type. (It's also the same for *all* systems/languages that claim IEEE754 conformance -- the equivalent C code does the *exact same thing* ;)

Comment: @J.C.Leitão Exactly as LThode replied. N.B. I'm not trying to denigrate recursive's accepted answer. If you were 10k you'd see a deleted answer from me that looks nearly identical!

Comment: @AdamSmith: I think it's a better answer than mine, wish I'd thought of it!

Comment: @LThode Why is it trollish?  There might be legitimate reasons to behave similar to `nan`.

Comment: @gerrit -- the "trollish" was a reference to Timgeb's answer below :) (It's merely surprising behavior for someone who is told "here's a value-type, go use it", by the way)

Comment: @LThode, my question was more on the spirit of: is defining `__eq__` as being incompatible with `id() == id()` a bad thing? If yes, why Python allows it? If not, then I would argue that @recursive just didn't found a good example for a custom class where the behaviour has an advantage.

Comment: @J.C.Leitão -- Python *must* allow it, or else you wouldn't be able to create a BigFloat UDT that implements the IEEE754 NaN semantics.  (This would be a real drag for a Python set of bindings to the [MPFR library](http://www.mpfr.org/), for instance.)

Comment: @J.C.Leitão -- to the spirit of your question, though -- it's a matter of the contract your users expect the type to provide.  A user-defined floating point type that didn't have fully unordered NaNs would be *extremely* surprising for scientific users who rely on the carefully crafted semantics of IEEE754, while irreflexive comparisons in a class that represents a parser token would be equally surprising to a compiler writer.

Answer (score 58):

The paper is right.  Consider the following.

```
class WeirdEquals:
    def __eq__(self, other):
        return False

w = WeirdEquals()
print("id(w) == id(w)", id(w) == id(w))
print("w == w", w == w)
```

Output is this:

```
id(w) == id(w) True
w == w False
```

Answer (score 25):

`id(o1) == id(o2)` does not imply `o1 == o2`.

Let's have a look at this `Troll` which overrides `__eq__` to always return `False`.

```
>>> class Troll(object):
...     def __eq__(self, other):
...         return False
... 
>>> a = Troll()
>>> b = a
>>> id(a) == id(b)
True
>>> a == b
False
```

That being said, there should be *very* few examples in the standard library where the object-ids match but `__eq__` can return `False` anyway, kudos @MarkMüller for finding a good example.

So either the objects are insane, very special (like nan), or concurrency bites you. Consider this extreme example, where `Foo` has a more reasonable `__eq__` method (which 'forgets' to check the ids) and `f is f` is always `True`.

```
import threading

class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 1

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return isinstance(other, Foo) and self.x == other.x

f = Foo()

class MutateThread(threading.Thread):
    def run(self):
        while True:
            f.x = 2
            f.x = 1

class CheckThread(threading.Thread):
    def run(self):
        i = 1
        while True:
            if not (f == f):
                print 'loop {0}: f != f'.format(i) 
            i += 1

MutateThread().start()
CheckThread().start()
```

Output:

```
$ python eqtest.py
loop 520617: f != f
loop 1556675: f != f
loop 1714709: f != f
loop 2436222: f != f
loop 3210760: f != f
loop 3772996: f != f
loop 5610559: f != f
loop 6065230: f != f
loop 6287500: f != f
...
```