# compare two custom lists python

Tags: python, list, compare

I'm having trouble comparing two list of objects in python

I'm converting a message into

```
class StatusMessage(object):
    def __init__(self, conversation_id, platform):
        self.__conversation_id = str(conversation_id)
        self.__platform = str(platform)

    @property
    def conversation_id(self):
        return self.__conversation_id

    @property
    def platform(self):
        return self.__platform
```

Now when I create two lists of type StatusMessage

```
>>> expected = []
>>> expected.append(StatusMessage(1, "abc"))
>>> expected.append(StatusMessage(2, "bbc"))

>>> actual = []
>>> actual.append(StatusMessage(1, "abc"))
>>> actual.append(StatusMessage(2, "bbc"))
```

and then I compare the two lists using

```
>>> cmp(actual, expected)
```

or

```
>>> len(set(expected_messages_list).difference(actual_list)) == 0
```

I keep getting failures.
When I debug and actually compare for each item  within the list like

```
>>> actual[0].conversation_id == expected[0].conversation_id
>>> actual[0].platform == expected[0].platform
```

then I always see

```
True
```

Doing below returns -1

```
>>> cmp(actual[0], expected[0])
```

why is this so. What am I missing???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must tell python how to check two instances of class `StatusMessage` for equality.

For example, adding the method

```
def __eq__(self,other):
    return (self is other) or (self.conversation_id, self.platform) == (other.conversation_id, other.platform)
```

will have the following effect:

```
>>> cmp(expected,actual)
0
>>> expected == actual
True
```

If you want to use `cmp` with your `StatusMessage` objects, consider implementing the `__lt__` and `__gt__` methods as well. I don't know by which rule you want to consider one instance lesser or greater than another instance.

In addition, consider returning `False` or error-checking for comparing a `StatusMessage` object with an arbitrary object that has no `conversation_id` or `platform` attribute. Otherwise, you will get an `AttributeError`:

```
>>> actual[0] == 1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "a.py", line 16, in __eq__
    return (self is other) or (self.conversation_id, self.platform) == (other.conversation_id, other.platform)
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'conversation_id'
```

You can find one reason why the `self is other` check is a good idea [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34599953/are-objects-with-the-same-id-always-equal-when-comparing-them-with/34600023#34600023) (possibly unexpected results in multithreaded applications).

Comment: Thanks timgeb for your answer. But this is the thing, when I compare the order of the elements in the list shouldnt matter. This is why my first approach was to use set and difference

Comment: Well I tried sorting the list and then did the comparision and it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are trying to compare two custom objects, you have to define what makes the objects equal or not. You do this by defining the `__eq__()` method on the `StatusMessage` class:

```
class StatusMessage(object):
    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.conversation_id == other.conversation_id and
               self.platform == other.platform
```